# Django - Functions in models and views don't return correct Boolean value

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, boolean-operations

I am creating a django app/website and am in trouble with some Boolean results I don't understand.

In my models, I have a Article class with 2 functions :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    #some vars
    basetime = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    has_begun = models.BooleanField()

    def remainingTime(self):
        if(self.basetime + self.duration) - time.time() >= 0:
            return ((self.basetime + self.duration) - time.time())
        else:
            return -1

    def stillAvailable(self):
        if self.remainingTime() >= 0:
            return True
        return False
```

And in my views I have a function check :

```
def check(request,i):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=i)
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        return ccm(request)

    if (article.stillAvailable):
        return test(request,article.remainingTime)
    else:
        return quid(request)
```

When a page calls check, my browser displays the test page, and the argument article.remainingTime is -1. (wich is the correct value for what I want to do).

My problem is : if article.remainingTime = -1, then article.stillAvailable should return False, and so the check function should return quid(request).
I don't see the reason why django/python interpreter evaluates article.stillAvailable True.

If anyone can help, that'd be very appreciated :P

Comment: How are you sure the `article.remainingTime` is `-1`? Did you put some logs in the `check` function?

Comment: The test view simply displays the given argument, and in my case it's -1. I also made a javascript alert displaying article.remainingTime, and it's -1 with this method too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
if (article.stillAvailable):
```

As a attribute, rather than calling it as a method. As the attribute exists, it's interpreted as non false. You just need to add the brackets to call the method.

Comment: Wow. I supposed the answer simple, but at this point... I have to work a bit more !

Anyway, thanks you !